# Как настроить stackoverflow, чтобы ответы приходили на почту?

Tags: обсуждение

Зашел на stackoverflow и оказалось, что у меня куча ответов, но их нет в моей почте, почему так?

Comment: А вы включали уведомления, когда создавали тему?

Answer (score 4):

Нажимаешь на свою аватарку. Нажимаешь "Править". Далее "Изменить Настройки Подписки". Смотришь, что там в пункте "Входящие сообщения".

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь, то по умолчанию и так раз в неделю входящие сообщения должны приходить по почте, если на сайт не заходить.

Comment: У меня нету пункта входящие сообщения